# Add controller - > Unable to load the service index for "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.json"

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

**error creating controller in VS C #**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try to reinstall the package with `Package Manager Console`:

```
Update-Package -reinstall -Source nuget.org
```

Comment: after following your instruction, it now displays this error: Couldn't load File or assembly 'EntityFramework Version 5.0.0.0'